# Some embed iframe html youtube videos are working but some videos are working. Why? And how to solve it?

Tags: html, iframe, youtube-api

> Some embed iframe html youtube videos are working but some videos are working. Please Give me solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<embed width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/v/_Yhyp-_hX2s"> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not working in localhost as well as my web heroku app.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide more info: do you get any errors? - read **[ask]** and how to provide a **[mcve]**.